# Make web map editable for group (arcgis.com)

Tags: arcgis-online

I've created and web map and shared it with a group on arcgis.com.  I want the other users of the group to be able to edit.

I'm sure its a simple permissions issue, but the other users are only able to "save as" and the "save" is disabled.

When I look at the share settings for the web map, the group is indeed selected.

- Web map is shared with the group
- The group is private
- I have the group contributors set to "All Members"

Are the other users in the group supposed to be able to edit the web map I create?  If so, how can I enable that?

Thanks in advance for any answers.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what type of feature service you are attempting to edit. From the [Help](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcgisonline/index.html#//010q00000047000000):

> > Features are representations of real-world objects drawn on the map. Most maps contain a common set of features, such as polygons outlining
> >     lakes, lines representing streets, and points showing specific places.
> >     In addition to these common features, many maps use a focused set of
> >     features to help you perform a specific task. For example, features
> >     outlining recreation areas within a national park might highlight
> >     potential conflicts between humans and natural resources, and a city's
> >     evacuation routes, depicted as lines, can be a reference for emergency
> >     aid organizations. Map authors can display attributes with pop-up
> >     windows, change the symbology, and set the visibility range for the
> >     features.
>
> You add a set of features as a layer to your map which can either be
>   edited by you, the map author, or anybody viewing the map. **Who can
>   edit features depends on the type of feature layer.** Features from a
>   service layer are editable by anybody viewing the map, so they are
>   useful when you want community input. For example, you might include a
>   service layer that allows the birding community to post their bird
>   sightings directly on the map and attach media files, such as
>   photographs, audio files, and video files, to the specific observation
>   points. Because these features are part of the service, any changes
>   made on the map are immediately viewable to everybody who has access
>   to the service. This type of layer is useful when you want others to
>   edit your features, you have large amounts of data, and you have
>   access to ArcGIS for Server.
>
> When feature layers are stored in the map, only the map author can
>   edit the features. In other words, your edits are saved when you save
>   your map. These types of feature layers are useful for displaying
>   information such as events happening within a community or inventory
>   of oil production facilities. If you have features in delimited text
>   file or GPX file, you can import them into your map. Feature layers
>   that are part of the map are also an easy way to add a small number of
>   features, for example, the swimming pools managed by your city's parks
>   and recreation department and when you don't have access to ArcGIS for
>   Server for creating feature service layers.

One way to get around this issue would be to [transfer the ownership](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcgisonline/index.html#/Managing_items/010q0000004w000000/) of the map to whoever is editing.

Comment: Hey thanks for the response.

So editing underlying features seems to be addressed, but what about the example of adding a new imagery layer.  I specifically want group users to be able to add/remove map layers. Is the owner the only one who can do that?